# Need to confirm this question about the spelling of "Android" is on-topic here

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have the question below:

> Most of the time when I'm trying to write the word **Android**, I get the confusion about it's spelling, like will it be Andorid or Android. So most of the time I was written wrong spelling.
>
> To overcome this issue is there any tips or a way to remember the confusion between placing the And(or/ro)id?

Is the question is on-topic here? If so what tag can I use?

Comment: @DanBron: Thanks for the response. I have posted in [main site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/130478/28470). Can you please share the same to there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, your question is on-topic. Here are a few similar questions that were well-received:

- [Is there a mnemonic that helps remembering when I should use "hate," and when "ate"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268/is-there-a-mnemonic-that-helps-remembering-when-i-should-use-hate-and-when-a)
- [How do I avoid misspelling "receive" as "recieve"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80542/how-do-i-avoid-misspelling-receive-as-recieve)
- [Uses of ' instal ' vs ' install '](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18896/uses-of-instal-vs-install).

Further, your problem is clearly stated and it is a practical spelling problem, which should be on-topic as suggested by the [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I recommend the tags [spelling](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling), [confusable](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confusable), and [mnemonic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonic).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have posted in [main site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/130478/28470)